# Budgie Installation?

Tags: budgie

Does anyone know what happened to Budgie?  I used the Gnome desktop when I first installed Ubuntu (about a year ago) but downloaded Budgie a few months ago and have been running it on both a desktop and a laptop.

Early this morning while I was working on the desktop I clicked on something that brought up a window saying that a complete installation of Budgie needed to be completed, and that the system would automatically reboot. I thought I'd already gone through this step on both systems, but went ahead and clicked on whatever...  When the computer finished rebooting, Budgie was gone. Completely gone.

I've tried re-installing it from every Budgie app in the Ubuntu Software list, but it never installs. Then I noticed that every single Budgie app in the Ubuntu Software list shows an update of August 27, 2019.  That's today's date (for me - it's just 7 a.m. where I am).

I'm running Ubuntu 19.04 and Gnome 3.32.1 on a Dell desktop, 64-bit Intel Core 2 Duo CPU E7500 @ 2.93GHz x 2.  Sorry I don't know enough to volunteer whatever else might be helpful.

I really like Budgie and would like to get it back. If anyone can help, I'd appreciate it!

---

So, I tried the suggested command (`sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade sudo apt install ubuntu-budgie-desktop`).  This is the output:

```
Hit:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco InRelease
Get:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-updates InRelease [97.5 kB]    
Hit:3 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu disco InRelease                      
Hit:4 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntubudgie/backports/ubuntu disco InRelease   
Get:5 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-security InRelease [97.5 kB]     
Get:6 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-backports InRelease [88.8 kB]
Fetched 284 kB in 1s (209 kB/s)                                      
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
2 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package install
```

It installed `ubuntu-budgie-welcome`. Let me log out and and see whether it shows up as an option for login...

No. Still just have a choice between Ubuntu / Ubuntu on Wayland / Unity.

I'm sorry to be sort of clueless about how some of this works.  I do remember having to reboot during the initial installation. I thought I had done that step on both the desktop and the laptop, but when I was asked to do it again this morning I assumed that I must not have done it.  (Sorry if I'm slight incoherent -I've been up all night.)

Actually, since I logged out and back in, the package that it installed (and I ran!) -- "ubuntu-budgie-welcome" -- is no longer to be found.

Either something is terribly wrong or I am really missing something. ;-/

I ran:  apt policy budgie-desktop 
Output was:

budgie-desktop:
   Installed: (none) 
   Candidate: 10.5-0ubuntu1.1
   Version table:
     10.5-0ubuntu1.1 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco/universe amd64 Packages
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco/universe i386 Packages

Update 8/28/19.
I came home early this morning (about 1:30 a.m.) and noticed that the update dates on all the Budgie apps have changed from 8/27/19 to 8/28/19. (one of them changed as I was checking them.) So I tried re-installing "ubuntu-budgie-welcome" and it seemed to work, until I ran the "Budgie Complete Installation" ...which brought up its window saying:

```
"Ubuntu Budgie Welcome is now a SNAP package. 
To complete the installation the budgie-welcome package 
 needs to be removed and the ubuntu-budgie-welcome snap package needs to be installed.  

 An automatic reboot will complete the installation.  

 Clicking Yes will complete the upgrade - continue?
```

and after the reboot, Budgie had disappeared again.

Then I noticed a question/answer that I'd somehow skipped over before - the question "How to install Ubuntu Budgie over Ubuntu 18.04" and an answer posted by N0rbert last August. I tried what N0rbert suggested - installing the Budgie desktop as a task from a terminal with:

```
 sudo add-apt-repository universe  
 sudo apt-get update  
 sudo apt-get install ubuntu-budgie-desktop^
```

and (lo and behold) I have Budgie up and running again.

My own programming days are many years behind me, and I'm new to Ubuntu (though I worked with Unix at Bell Labs 30 years ago). But I wonder if I have something tweaked on my system (since it's not exclusively Budgie) that kept the installation package I was trying to use from Ubuntu Software from running correctly -- but executing the apt-get commands directly through a terminal was able to force the installation to succeed...? or were those two things actually different in some way I don't understand?  (e.g. an entirely Budgie version of Ubuntu vs. a simple desktop over Gnome-Ubuntu?)

Anyhow, I'm glad to be up and running again, though I've not yet had the courage to re-install "Budgie Complete Installation".  :)

So, my final question (given this is the first question I've ever posted here):
Do I now close this question?
And if so, how do I do that?

Comment: Surprize that it mention an automatic reboot, that is usually not linux's way.  Linux/Ubuntu will ask for a reboot when you feel like it.  To install you should only need to do these commands ```sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt install ubuntu-budgie-desktop```.  Copied from this page.  https://itsfoss.com/install-budgie-ubuntu/

Comment: Steeldriver - thank you for cleaning up my posting! I will try to learn how to do better.

Comment: It might be better to download from here, https://ubuntubudgie.org/downloads .  It will be the complete ubuntu OS with the budgie desktop and can then install it over what you have now(deleting everything) or install in a new partition and dual boot.  Sometimes different desktops don't play nice together.  Back up everything you want to keep if you decide to go this way.

Comment: Did you really run `sudo apt upgrade sudo apt install ubuntu-budgie-desktop` as a single command, or `sudo apt upgrade` and then `sudo apt install ubuntu-budgie-desktop` separately? What is the output of `apt policy budgie-desktop`? FWIW I'm generally suspicious of PPAs, especially now `budgie-desktop` is in the disco `universe` repository.

Comment: Yeah, I ran it all together as a single command.  (Been up too many hours!)

Comment: crip659 - thank you for the suggestion. I may just wait until the next major release of ubuntu - due in October ?  Your point about different desktops is well taken. Now that I feel comfortable switching over to Budgie completely, it makes sense to load just the budgie version.

Comment: You don't have to close the question. You can write your solution as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0):

I got Budgie running on my system again, thanks to an answer posted by N0rbert last August (in answer to the question "How to install Ubuntu Budgie over Ubuntu 18.04") by installing the Budgie desktop as a task from a terminal with:

```
  sudo add-apt-repository universe  
  sudo apt-get update  
  sudo apt-get install ubuntu-budgie-desktop^
```

Budgie is running fine now, though I did not find any definitive answer to the question of why installing Budgie from the Ubuntu Software GUI did not work on my system.